# How to sort in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

Hi I have a VARIABLE with that information:

```
17959025 0 -rw-r--r-- 1 u192 alum 0 Mar 24 16:00 fileA
17959026 0 -rw-r--r-- 1 u192 alum 0 Mar 24 15:58 fileB
Files found in /u/alum/u192/SO/DIR1
17959029 0 -rw-r--r-- 1 u192 alum 0 Mar 24 15:59 fileA
17959731 0 -rw-r--r-- 1 u192 alum 0 Mar 24 16:11 fileB
17959031 0 -rw-r--r-- 1 u192 alum 0 Mar 24 16:10 fileE
Files found in /u/alum/u192/SO/DIR2
```

And i would to sort for example by the inode, but if i do this:

```
VAR=`echo $VAR| sort -k 1`
```

the result is that

```
17959025 0 -rw-r--r-- 1 u192 alum 0 Mar 24 16:00 fileA
17959326 0 -rw-r--r-- 1 u192 alum 0 Mar 24 15:58 fileB
17959029 0 -rw-r--r-- 1 u192 alum 0 Mar 24 15:59 fileA
17959031 0 -rw-r--r-- 1 u192 alum 0 Mar 24 16:00 fileE
18092218 0 -rw-r--r-- 1 u192 alum 0 Mar 24 15:59 fileD
18092219 0 -rw-r--r-- 1 u192 alum 0 Mar 24 16:00 fileB
Files found in /u/alum/u192/SO/DIR1
Files found in /u/alum/u192/SO/DIR2
```

How can i distinguish the rows? Because I want to sorted and it has to be like the first example given.

Comment: split by the block delimiter, sort separately, then merge.

Comment: Why wouldn't `ls -li | sort` do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk:

```
echo "$VAR" | gawk 'BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc" } /^Files/ { for(p in lines) { printf("%s", lines[p]) } delete lines; print; next } { lines[$1] = lines[$1] $0 ORS }'
```

That is:

```
BEGIN {
  # make array traversal happen in numerically ascending order of indices.
  # This is a GNU extension and requires gawk.
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc" 
}
/^Files/ {                     # in a separator line
  for(p in lines) {            # wade through cached lines in that order
    printf("%s", lines[p])     # print them
  }
  delete lines                 # clear the cache
  print                        # print the separator line
  next                         # and be done
}
{                              # in other lines:
  lines[$1] = lines[$1] $0 ORS # remember them by the key (first field in
                               # this case). It is appended instead of
                               # assigned so that duplicate key values don't
                               # lead to dropped lines.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `echo $VAR` will produce a single line of output. You want

```
echo "$VAR" | sort -k 1
```

Comment: This doesn't address the problem of the interspersed "Files found" lines.

Comment: @chepner Hmm, that's not how I interpreted the question, but you may be right.  What do you think the problem is and how should it be resolved?